# How to stop flickers in Vim under windows

Tags: vim

In Vim 7.3, when I press "**K**" even if the cursor is already on the first line, or I do copy etc., then there is lots of flickers and also the buffer window invert its color.

Is there some way I can fix it.

Comment: Does it also happen when you start vim with **--noplugin**?

Comment: No

When I start vim normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn off `visualbell`

```
:set novb
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about that but it must be a plugin setting the switch.

Comment: @dearvivekkumar - As a Vim novice and always trying to learn something new: did you find *where* the flag got turned on? Did you add this solution to your vimrc as a quick fix? Did you disable or alter a plugin? Did you decide to reset the flag manually every time you start Vim *(I hope not <g>)*?

Comment: @Lieven

Yeah in my vimrc file I had set :set visualbell which was causing this. I have corrected that.

I didn't get what you mean by this.